# Reading rich text from an Excel cell

Tags: c#, excel

I am attempting to read an excel spreadsheet in which some cells contain rich text.  I would like to convert this to a plain text format that encodes the formatting in some way.  For example, given the text:

"Here's some text *with italics in the middle* of it."

I would like to convert this to:

"Here's some text [i]with italics in the middle[/i] of it".

The problem is that I haven't found a way to extract rich text from an excel cell.  `Interop.Office.Excel` allows me to get a `Range` and examine its `Style` property, but that only tells me whether the cell itself is italicized; it doesn't give me information about any of the individual characters.  The best ["solution"](http://www.bloodforge.com/post/Extract-Formatted-Text-From-Excel-Cell-With-C.aspx) I've found involves copying the contents of the cell to the clipboard and calling `Clipboard.GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf)`, and it's too slow to be practical.

Is there a smart way to access the rich text contained in an excel cell that I'm missing?

Comment: This is not quite a duplicate of [this question on converting rich text in an Excel cell to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620147/convert-rich-text-to-html-formatting-tags), but the answers to that question are likely to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The way to access the format of individual characters in a string is to use the `Range.Characters` object

To demonstrate here is a simple UDF in VBA that does the Italic format you describe.  You can extend it to detect any other formats you need

```
Function DecodeText(r As Range) As Variant
    Dim strDecoded As String
    Dim bItalic As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    If TypeName(r.Value) = "String" Then

        bItalic = False
        strDecoded = r
        j = 1
        For i = 1 To Len(strDecoded)
            If Not bItalic And r.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic Then
                strDecoded = Left(strDecoded, j - 1) & "[i]" & Mid(strDecoded, j)
                bItalic = True
                j = j + 3
            ElseIf bItalic And Not r.Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic Then
                strDecoded = Left(strDecoded, j - 1) & "[/i]" & Mid(strDecoded, j)
                bItalic = False
                j = j + 4
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Next
        If bItalic Then strDecoded = strDecoded & "[/i]"
        DecodeText = strDecoded
    Else
        DecodeText = r
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: The problem is that this is even slower than the aforementioned solution of copying the rich text to the clipboard.  Making a separate call to excel to read each character isn't really feasible.  I'm looking for a way to read it all at once and then parse it myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
i dont have answer for your question
```

but I suggest you to study the site
 http://www.winnovative-software.com/
 from this site you can get wnuxls.dll 
file which have all the functionality which we want to perform with excel try it