# Convert Rich Text to HTML formatting tags

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with an Excel list and want to turn:

*Quercus agrifolia* var. *oxyadenia* (Torr.) J.T. Howell

into:

```
<i>Quercus agrifolia</i> var. <i>oxyadenia</i> (Torr.) J.T. Howell
```

I have the Rich Text formatted list with formatting applied but I want to send it to Access with the formatting tags explicitly included around the related text.

Comment: @pnuts The macro here (http://community.hpe.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/Retain-the-formatting-while-exporting-from-Excel-to-QC/td-p/5217106) does the opposite of what I want, converting html tagged text to rich text within excel. I want my cell to have explicit html tags so I can export the formatting that has been previously applied to the cell values. I hope that answers the Q, and thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was looking to do the same thing, and found an answer on MSDN at:
[Convert contents of a formatted excel cell to HTML format](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/626a351a-de17-4389-9ad6-a2be20ce2fd9/convert-contents-of-a-formatted-excel-cell-to-html-format)

I hope this helps you as well, it uses an excel macro.

Edit:
When using this I needed to modify the code for nested tags, please find my updates to the macro below:

```
Function fnConvert2HTML(myCell As Range) As String
    Dim bldTagOn, itlTagOn, ulnTagOn, colTagOn As Boolean
    Dim i, chrCount As Integer
    Dim chrCol, chrLastCol, htmlTxt, htmlEnd As String

    bldTagOn = False
    itlTagOn = False
    ulnTagOn = False
    colTagOn = False
    chrCol = "NONE"
    'htmlTxt = "<html>"
    htmlTxt = ""
    chrCount = myCell.Characters.Count

    For i = 1 To chrCount
    htmlEnd = ""
        With myCell.Characters(i, 1)
            If (.Font.Color) Then
                chrCol = fnGetCol(.Font.Color)
                If Not colTagOn Then
                    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "<font color=#" & chrCol & ">"
                    colTagOn = True
                Else
                    If chrCol <> chrLastCol Then htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</font><font color=#" & chrCol & ">"
                End If
            Else
                chrCol = "NONE"
                If colTagOn Then
                    htmlEnd = "</font>" & htmlEnd
                    'htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</font>"
                    colTagOn = False
                End If
            End If
            chrLastCol = chrCol

            If .Font.Bold = True Then
                If Not bldTagOn Then
                    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "<b>"
                    bldTagOn = True
                End If
            Else
                If bldTagOn Then
                    'htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</b>"
                    htmlEnd = "</b>" & htmlEnd
                    bldTagOn = False
                End If
            End If

            If .Font.Italic = True Then
                If Not itlTagOn Then
                    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "<i>"
                    itlTagOn = True
                End If
            Else
                If itlTagOn Then
                    'htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</i>"
                    htmlEnd = "</i>" & htmlEnd
                    itlTagOn = False
                End If
            End If

            If .Font.Underline > 0 Then
                If Not ulnTagOn Then
                    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "<u>"
                    ulnTagOn = True
                End If
            Else
                If ulnTagOn Then
                    'htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</u>"
                    htmlEnd = "</u>" & htmlEnd
                    ulnTagOn = False
                End If
            End If

            If (Asc(.Text) = 10) Then
                htmlTxt = htmlTxt & htmlEnd & "<br>"
            Else
                htmlTxt = htmlTxt & htmlEnd & .Text
            End If

        End With
    Next

    If colTagOn Then
        htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</font>"
        colTagOn = False
    End If
    If bldTagOn Then
        htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</b>"
        bldTagOn = False
    End If
    If itlTagOn Then
        htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</i>"
        itlTagOn = False
    End If
    If ulnTagOn Then
        htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</u>"
        ulnTagOn = False
    End If
    'htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</html>"
    fnConvert2HTML = htmlTxt
End Function

Function fnGetCol(strCol As String) As String
    Dim rVal, gVal, bVal As String
    strCol = Right("000000" & Hex(strCol), 6)
    bVal = Left(strCol, 2)
    gVal = Mid(strCol, 3, 2)
    rVal = Right(strCol, 2)
    fnGetCol = rVal & gVal & bVal
End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I found that iterating over `Range.Characters` was too slow for my needs – it took more than 5 seconds on my computer to convert a single cell with 1,000 characters of content, even after [avoiding the string concatenation problem with a string builder class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67596/a-lightning-fast-stringbuilder).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative solution which is faster, but produces messier output (because it uses Word's HTML engine). You need to add the following references to your VBA project:

- Microsoft HTML Object Library
- Microsoft Scripting Runtime
- Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library

Then, call the following code by running eg. `convertToHtml(Range("A1:A100"))` in the immediate window:

```
' Given a temporary file path, load the HTML in that file
' and return the first paragraph's inner HTML.
Function extractFirstParagraph(filePath As String) As String
    Dim fs As New FileSystemObject, _
        html As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument, _
        par As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
    html.body.innerHTML = fs.OpenTextFile(filePath).ReadAll
    Set par = html.getElementsByTagName("P")(0)
    extractFirstParagraph = par.innerHTML
End Function

Sub convertToHtml(rng As Range)
    ' Open a single Word instance.
    Dim w As New Word.Application, d As Word.Document
    Set d = w.Documents.Add

    Dim cell As Range
    Const tempFile As String = "c:\temp\msword.html"
    ' For each cell in the range ...
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            ' ... copy it into the Word document ...
            cell.Copy
            d.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            ' ... save the Word document as HTML
            ' in a temporary file ...
            d.SaveAs2 tempFile, wdFormatHTML
            ' ... and extract the first paragraph.
            cell.Value = extractFirstParagraph(tempFile)
            Debug.Print "Cell " & cell.Address & " done."
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Close Word once you're done. Note that if a bug
    ' is encountered, this cleanup won't occur and the 
    ' Word process will need to be killed to release
    ' file locks, otherwise you get an unhelpful error.
    w.Quit False
End Sub
```

You can clean up the output using regular expressions by adding a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5, and running a function like this:

```
' Used to avoid duplication in cleanWordHtml.
Function eraseInPlace(ByRef r As RegExp, _
    ByRef s As String, p As String) As String
    r.Pattern = p
    s = r.Replace(s, "")
End Function

' Eliminate junk tags from HTML generated by Word.
Function cleanWordHtml(inputString As String)
    Dim r As New RegExp
    r.Global = True
    eraseInPlace r, inputString, "mso-[^;""]*(; )?"
    eraseInPlace r, inputString, " style="""""
    eraseInPlace r, inputString, "<\?xml[^>]*>"
    eraseInPlace r, inputString, "<\/?o:[^>]*>"
    eraseInPlace r, inputString, "<SPAN><\/SPAN>"
    cleanWordHtml = inputString
End Function
```

If you need to convert `<span>` tags to `<font>` tags (I also needed to do this because I was importing into an Access rich text field, which doesn't support CSS), try calling this function and passing in the MSHTML objects constructed in the `extractFirstParagraph` function:

```
' Given a <p> DOM node, replace any children of the
' form <span style="color: foo"> with <font color="foo">.
Function convertSpanToFont(ByRef par As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement, _
    ByRef doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)
    Dim span As MSHTML.HTMLSpanElement, _
        font As MSHTML.HTMLFontElement
    For Each span In par.getElementsByTagName("span")
        Set font = doc.createElement("font")
        If IsNull(span.Style.Color) _
            Or span.Style.Color <> "" Then
            font.Color = span.Style.Color
            font.innerHTML = span.innerHTML
            span.insertAdjacentElement "afterEnd", font
            span.removeNode True
        End If
    Next span
End Function
```

I also considered just saving the whole spreadsheet as HTML from Excel and then using another tool to get that into a format that Access can deal with, but Excel's HTML export generates CSS classes rather than inline styles. This method is also helpful if you only need to convert part of your spreadsheet to HTML.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a much cleaner and faster solution using Excel's internal XML-representation and transforming it with an XSL-Stylesheet.

You can find VBA-Code and the required XSLT on https://github.com/HeimMatthias/Excel-HTML-Tools-Public

*Disclaimer:* I've written this tool myself after using the unforgivably slow VBA-script for years. Sample output can be seen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mheim/u5L63cg1/).

**For technical details:**

The [`Range.Value`-Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Value) can take a parameter [`xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlrangevaluedatatype), with which it returns a fully formatted xml-String that includes an html-object of its contents.
Running `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet)` on a cell containing

> *Quercus agrifolia* var. *oxyadenia* (Torr.) J.T. Howell

returns the following String:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62">
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"
    ss:Italic="1"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Tabelle1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1"
   ss:DefaultColumnWidth="61.714285714285708"
   ss:DefaultRowHeight="14.571428571428571">
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><ss:Data ss:Type="String"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><I><Font html:Color="#000000">Quercus agrifolia</Font></I><Font
       html:Color="#000000"> var. </Font><I><Font html:Color="#000000">oxyadenia</Font></I><Font
       html:Color="#000000"> (Torr.) J.T. Howell</Font></ss:Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

The `Cell`-Tag surrounds an `ss:Data`-Object containing -- more or less -- clean html-Code. In any case, it is much simpler and much faster to sanitize this data to obtain clean html than to parse over each letter and access its styles. (By much faster, I mean easily a factor of 100x faster).

**Things to watch out for:** Cell-styles (both from the template and the individual cell) are not represented as html. This isn't always particularly obvious. In the example above, the cell has automatically received an italic styling, because the first word has been italicized. Since there are also roman (upright) words in the string, the code for the italic passages is represented in the html. But if the entire cell were italicized the `<i>`-tags would be missing. This is particularly confusing, because you cannot just surround the entire html with an `<i>`-Tag if the corresponding style has `ss:Italic="1"` as a property, you will also need to check whether it includes -Tags inside the html-part. This, of course, applies to all cell styles.

Comment: Note, that -- of course -- Excel's html-Export is even cleaner. So if you do not require programmatical extraction and want to export the full file, this may be the best solution for you.